# Disabling the ability to add, upload or drag and drop folders into a document library - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, content-type, folder, drag-and-drop

My company is implementing a sharepoint structure of a single hub site consisting of many sites, no subsites. We don't want the presence of folders being in our sharepoint online document libraries. We only want to use document sets and documents. I have already removed the folder option in the "New" menu, and sharepoint designer has prevented users to upload folders into specific libraries through the "upload" menu, however users can still drag and drop folders into document libraries.

When I try to remove the folder content type(0x0120) from the site altogether in sharepoint designer, it states that it could not save changes. I found a way to disable the drag and drop feature, but I still want users to be able to drag and drop documents.

It there any way to remove the folder content type completely from the site?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to remove the folder content type from the site in sharepoint online. This is by design. The only way you can do is to disable creating folder in library advanced settings one by one.

[image]

Besides, if you are familiar with powershell, you could also use powershell to disable it.

Comment: I think that only removes the command from UI, but will not stop creating folders from the drag and drop.